# How to back up PostgreSQL using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql, backup

I have a problem. I want to ask you all about how to back up database from vb.net. I'm using PostgreSQL. Why I need back up database? Because it's too large to display all at datagridview when it's running. So for a time span, example 3 months, it's automatically backed-up. I always get Messagebox "Error at or near Backup. Error while executingnonquer
 Thank you

```
koneksi()
Try
    Dim fname As String
    Dim db2 As String = "aplikasilis2"
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objdlg As New SaveFileDialog
    objdlg.FileName = "C : \Documents\Arsip 3 bulan_" + FormatTglUniversal(Date.Now) + ".bak"
    objdlg.ShowDialog()
    fname = objdlg.FileName
    Dim data_affector As Integer
    strQuery = "Backup database =" & db2 & " To disk ='" & fname & "'"
    Try
        cmdBackup = New OdbcCommand(strQuery, conn)
        data_affector = cmdBackup.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox("berhasil")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure that PostgreSQL supports backing up using SQL code like that?  I've not used it much but I've just done a quick search and everything I can find about backing up uses something else.

Comment: It looks like I was on the right track.  Read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132083/query-to-back-up-a-postgresql-database). Note that you would call `Process.Start` to run the 'pg_dump' commandline app.

Comment: I don't know either. I've already been using PostgreSQL. Backing up is a new demand of my project. It's impossible to change my database @jmcilhinney

Comment: Wait.. Bak file type are for `sql server` not postgresql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't backup `Postgresql` use `query` as stated in comment by @jmcilhinney and the link to refer your question it's clear.

In `Postgresql` Documentation there are no information about that too:

[**Backup Use pg_dump**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html) or [**Backup**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup.html)

But using `pg_dump` will give you a full `sql` file including all `DDL` and `DML` statements to recreate your database in another place (or restore).

And Big system too like `Odoo` or `iDempiere` as `ERP` use database `Postgresql` do backup too using `pg_dump` command.

`Odoo` : [**How To Backup Odoo**](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-backup-84929)

`iDempiere` : [**How To Backup iDempiere**](http://learnidempiere.blogspot.com/2017/02/backup-postgressql-database.html)

Just accept it you can't do that from `Query` statement and make meeting your project about this..

Comment: so, would you like to review this?i'm trying use pg_dump as command line, but it still have a problem

Comment: What do you mean review?

Comment: ok. I got it. I've trying use pg_dump as you both said. But this still have an problem, would you like to correct this?  Dim pg_dump As String
        Dim fname As String
        fname = "C:\Documents\testbackup.sql"
        pg_dump = "-Fp -v -h  PostgreSQL ANSI -p 5433 -U postgres -d aplikasilis2 -f " + fname + " "
        Process.Start(pg_dump)

Comment: No.. It is not query statement.. See the documentation.. Run it use cmd..

Comment: Oh see about psql command.. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: So, do you mean I must link vb.net with cmd? @dwir182

Comment: So, do you mean I must link vb.net with cmd? @dwir182

Comment: Just use cmd instead.. Do it outside program.. What are you trying to do are backup like sql server do.. But postgresql different..

Comment: Oooo, ok. I got it. Thank you very much. May I ask one more question? Do you have any idea for my project? I want to back up my data. If i use datagridview, It only save one table from my database

Comment: If this answer help you could you accept it as answer? :)  and you could ask about opinion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182554/discussion-between-winda-sari-elisabeth-siburian-and-dwir182).